# formbuilder angular

Tags: angular, typescript, formbuilder

I wanted to include the notes to the formbuilder , so that I can use or call the formcontrolname. the questions that I map contains the notes. I wanted to include the notes on the formbuilder.notes is a string inside questions object.

#Code

```js
initFormGroups(): void {
  const sectionGroups = {};
  this._sections.map((section: TemplateSection, sectionIndex: number) => {
    const sectionGroup = {};

    section.questions.map(
      ({ rephrase, question, notes }: Question, questionIndex) => {
        sectionGroup[questionIndex] = [rephrase || question];
      }
    );

    sectionGroups[sectionIndex] = this.formBuilder.group(sectionGroup);

    return null;
  });

  this.form = this.formBuilder.group(sectionGroups);
}
```

#something like

```js
this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
  notes: [ notes ] 
});
```

#template

```html
<editor
  class="mat-input-element"
  [disabled]="true"
  matInput
  formControlName="notes"
  [init]="tinyMCEConfig"
>
</editor>
```

Comment: What is `notes`? An array of strings? A string? Also, your use of `Array.prototype.map` is poor practice because your callbacks don't return values and you're throwing away the resulting arrays. Use `Array.prototype.forEach` in such cases. Why? Because when someone reads that code, those `map` calls looks like bugs.

Comment: @AluanHaddad do you have some suggestion on the refactoring of that code Sir ? can you please post ?. Notes is a string inside a questions object

Comment: @AluanHaddad Notes is a string